# Why do i see [object Object] inside my input?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I can't understand why instead of a placeholder inside my input I see `[object Object]`;

Here is my **html**:

```
<div class="input-form">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Type name here..." [(ngModel)]="newItem">
  <button (click)="addItem()">Add new</button>
</div>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items">{{ item }}
    <button (click)="deleteItem(item)" >Delete</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And here is **component.ts**:

```
newItem = {};
items = [];

addItem() {
  if (this.newItem !== null) {
    this.items.push(this.newItem);
    this.newItem = {};
  }
}
```

Comment: As you have defined `newItem = {}`  getting the result define it as `newItem = '';`

Comment: If yo uwant to keep it as an object, try with the json pipe : `{{ item | json }}`

Answer (score 3):

`[object Object]` is result of `toString()` function.

```
const obj = { };
console.log(obj.toString());
```

result:

`[object Object]`

You need to pass value of `string` type, but I highly recommend not to pass value with `ngModel` at all. You should use `FormGroup` to create forms.

Comment: `FormGroup` is definitely the way to go, even for really simple input. I would suggest getting used to using it so that you will get better at writing quick forms. It is a great tool.

Answer (score 1):

You should define `newItem` as *string* because it refers to *binding* target value which comes from your `input` *element*.

```
newItem: string;
```